# IPython cannot run scripts with % in them

Tags: ipython

Simply put this `.py` file:

```py
%$timeit 54
```

Results in:

```
barnes_hut main % $ ipython .\scripts\test_timeit.py
  File ~\Documents\GitHub\barnes_hut\scripts\test_timeit.py:1
    %$timeit 54
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to not save `.py` but as `.ipy`.